# How to sort a table by checking the value of a specific field and then sorting the others differently

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model for `Notifications` in my app, and one of the fields is `event_type`, to make what even generated the notification.

The mobile clients using our API want the notifications to come back sorted in a particular way via making a single request.

They want all notifications with an `event_type` of `connection_invite` to come back first, and then all notifications of other `event_type`s sorted by `created_at desc`.

So a collection of `Notifications` like:

```
[
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 1, event_type: "content_assigned", created_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 1, event_type: "connection_invite", created_at: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 3, event_type: "post_created", created_at: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 4, event_type: "connection_invite", created_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>
]
```

would return the collection sorted like:

```
[
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 4, event_type: "connection_invite", created_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 2, event_type: "connection_invite", created_at: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Fri, 20 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 3, event_type: "post_created", created_at: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sun, 22 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>,
 #<Notification:0x007f id: 1, event_type: "content_assigned", created_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:10:56 UTC +00:00, updated_at: Sat, 21 Oct 2017 21:16:14 UTC +00:00>,
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the sort order in the query:

```
order by ( (event_type = 'connection_invite')::int desc),
         created_at desc
```